# Problema tamaño de fuente al exportar reporte de Crystal Reports a PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

Estoy trabajando una aplicacion web [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) con [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) y en la parte de reportes estoy trabajando con [crystal-report](/questions/tagged/crystal-report) version para VS13 que es donde me he encontrado con el problema que al exportar a PDF el tamaño de fuente se hace más pequeño. ¿Como puedo corregir este problema?

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución.

para las versiones completas de [cristal-report](/questions/tagged/cristal-report) menciona que existe en regedit una clave llamada **ForceLargerFonts** la cual no existen el la versión para VS.

La solucion esta en crear dicha clave en el regedit dentro de `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export.`

Crear una nueva clave llamada **PDF** y dentro de ella un nuevo valor **DWORD** con el nombre de **ForceLargerFonts** y valor de **1**.

Quedara de la siguiente manera:
[image: regedit]

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo había tenido el mismo problema con la extensión de Crystal report para Visual Studio.

Para solucionar dicho problema va a sonar algo simple y sencillo: Aumento el tamaño de la Fuente del reporte (esto es debido que la extensión de Crystal report altera el formato del reporte original).

Asi mismo adquirir el software que diseña los reportes de Crystal report (la cual brinda muchas herramientas para hacer tu reporte), y no altera tanto tu reporte.

Otra recomendación es la técnica de prueba y error,  ya que genero el reporte y comparo el resultado (el archivo y el documento impreso), hasta que se aprueba el diseño del reporte.

Saludos, espero resolver tu problema.

Comment: ya lo intente y cambia drasticamente el formato del reporte, ya que me han entregado una plantilla de como deberia de quedar

Comment: ¿Será posible enseñar el formato modelo (El que el cliente desea) y el formato que te genera?

Comment: encontre la solucion Diego, muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: solo hay que crear la clave ForceLargerFonts dentro del regedit ya que en Crystal para VS no existe